# Cannot connect to MSSQL 2008 with ip 127.0.0.1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I dont have much experience with MsSql. I have no problem to connect to database by SQL management studio with `SQL Server Authentication Mode` on ip `127.0.0.1`. 
But my program fails to connect. I created file `connect.UDL` for test connection and got this error

```
[DBNETLIB][ConnetionOpen (Invalid Instance()).] Invalid connection
```

Some information may usefull

- SQL server is on configured as Mixed Authentication Mode
- DIsabled my firewall
- Enabled all protocols (Shared Memory, Pipe names, TCP/IP, VIA)
- Using 127.0.0.1 and 1433 port for TCP/IP protocol
- Allowing remote connection on server

Can provide more information if you need. Thanks

**EDIT :** I deleted everything and installed SQL SERVER 2008 R2. Everything working now. Thanks all for your effort.

Comment: what is the code in your program that is trying to connect? Are you trying to connect from the same machine that SQL Management Studio is using?

Comment: @ElectricLlama Yes same device. Everything is on my PC

Comment: Try *(local)* instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Post the code that fails to connect. ("my program fails to connect")

Comment: Or open your UDL in notepad and post the connection string you find in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have installed SQL Server as a "Default instance" in order to be able to connect with just the IP address or hostname. If it's a "Named instance" installation, you will need to specify the hostname and instance name to connect. (i.e. MY_HOST\MY_INSTANCE)

Check out the SQL Server Configuration Manager, and under SQL Server 2008 Services section, does the installation have the "Names instance" in brackets? - That's your named instance.

Comment: It is installed as Defualt instance.

Comment: Have you got telnet installed?

In CMD type telnet [HOSTNAME] 1433 to see if it connects.

Comment: it wasnt connecting. I installed 2008 R2. Now everything is working perfect